# Using matplotlib to draw rectangles with dates as coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on creating a graph that represents activity over time, modelled after a [chart in Sleep As Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le5HC.jpg).  It's similar to a heatmap, but does not use color variation. Each column is a date, and the y axis is the full duration of the day.  Whatever intervals of time where an activity occurs are blocked off with a bar.  Here's what I have so far:
[image]

So far I have only been able to accomplish this by manually plotting rectangles on the figure.  I loop through a list of events with dates, start times, and end times, plotting them like so:

```
ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((31*event_month + event_day, end_time), # (x,y)
                                0.75,                                  # width
                                duration))                             # height
```

This date handling is clearly wrong - it's just for the purpose of demonstration.

Normally when creating a histogram, I can plot using date objects directly with something like this:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.fmt_xdata = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I'd like to be able to somehow just use the date objects directly when plotting.  Is there a way to accomplish this in pyplot, or do I need to do something like converting the x axis to use POSIX time and just calculating where I put date labels?